# How to get the characters before the last “-” only if the string after the last "-" is numeric?

Tags: php, strpos

Suppose I have string like `$string = 'About-Us'`, then I will get formatted data as `$fdata = 'About-Us'`

However, if `$string = 'About-Us-2'`, then I will get formatted data as `$fdata = 'About-Us'` and `$remain_data = '2'`.

I am using this code:-

```
$fdata = substr( $string, 0, strrpos( $string, '-' ) );
```

However, the above code also strips out `$fdata = 'About'`, when `$string = 'About-Us'`.

How can I cut out string from last "-" only when the last "-" is followed by a numeric string?

Comment: Well i tried your version too and it worked!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are on the right way. `strpos` is looking for the last occurrence of a substring.

So you can just check if the last string is numeric:

```
$string = 'About-Us-2';
$fdata = is_numeric(substr($string, strrpos( $string, '-' )+1, strlen($string))) ? substr( $string, 0, strrpos( $string, '-' ) ) : $string;
$remain_data = is_numeric(substr($string, strrpos( $string, '-' )+1, strlen($string))) ? substr($string, strrpos( $string, '-' )+1, strlen($string)) : '';
echo $fdata;
echo $remain_data;
```

Answer (score 1):

Your code is not working the way you want because your statement checks the first occurance of '-'.
try this:-

```
$remain_data = substr($string, strrpos($string,'-'), -1);
$fdata = str_replace($remain_data, '', $string);
```

I hope this works for you.

Answer (score 0):

check following code:

```
$string = 'About-Us-2';
$string = preg_replace('/[0-9]+/', '', $string);//it will remove all numerics
$string = trim($string, '-');// then trim last '-'
```

the output will be:

```
About-Us
```

Comment: And what if there is no number at the end, just "About-us"? I think the problem was with this one.

Comment: `trim()` is no longer needed, you may markup regex pattern to reduce code.